# Is an SQL database appropriate to store many players and their games?

Tags: sql, nosql

I'm writing a backend for the newer version of a pretty popular game. (5M+ players, over 50M games per month).

Is SQL a good choice as a storage system to save the players' profile and their games ? Namely, I'm afraid of the performances of a join on such big tables.

Here's what we want to do :

- have an "achievement" mechanism ("You just played your 10 000th game", or "You have been playing for N days")
- be able to show, for a given player, his "track record" of past games

Comment: What would you wanna do otherwise?

Comment: There are tons of options. NoSQL database for example.

Answer (score 6):

SQl Server handles far more data than that easily. I know of SQL Server databases that track stock market changes for instance. But you need to have a database sepcialist do the design for a high performance, large system. Asking an application programmer to do this design is like asking your Gynecologist to fix your lung cancer.

Answer (score 4):

It should handle it with no problem. I have had a table with over 2 billion rows and as long as your indexing is correct it will be fine.

You also consider table partitioning [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) for large datasets.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper indexing" ? Personally I've experienced massive slowdowns on insertion in tables that had "only" over 1M lines. And they only had an index on their primary key.

Comment: Proper indexing considers what the main usage of the data is. If its selection or insert changes the required index patterns. [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-indexes-the-basics) should help.

Comment: @ecco, if you had that they there was something very wrong in your design. Were you by chance using GUIDs in a clustered index?